# multilingual websites for search engines

Tags: html, seo, multilingual

I have a website in German and English.

- http://www.example.com/en/posts/1
- http://www.example.com/de/posts/1

If you go to website without the "en" or "de" in the url http://www.example.com/posts/1 I check the browser language and deceide what language the users prefers.

So if an english user visits the site http://www.example.com/posts/1 I show the english content and add to all links on the page the "en" language(no redirect). On the next click on a link the user switches to "en" version.

On each site I have the hreflang entries

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de/posts/1" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/posts/1" />
```

The Problem is that the search engines add the http://www.example.com/posts/1 to their index.

1.) How can I avoid that? Do I have to set a canonical link to one language?

2.) Is it better to redirect the user to language site?

Comment: You need to explain the current situation more. Do the language-specific versions actually exist as addressable pages? Showing a real URL might help a lot in the analysis. Anyway, language selection by “browser language” (whatever that means) is not a good starting point. (Someone may well use English version of a browser even if his native language is German.) For just two languages, you could simply have one of the versions as primary and make it contain a link to the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google covers this in two blog posts:

- [Working with multilingual websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html)
- [New markup for multilingual content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html)